# How do I find the gcd of all numbers in a tuple using math.gcd?

Tags: python

```
from math import gcd
nums = tuple(map(int,input().split()))
# find gcd of numbers in num
```

I tried the following code

```
print(gcd(nums))
```

but "TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" occures.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gcd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) takes an arbitrary number of positional args not an iterable, you need to unpack your tuple into positional args when you call it.

```
print(gcd(*nums))
```

NOTE: This was added in Python 3.9.

> Changed in version 3.9: Added support for an arbitrary number of arguments. Formerly, only two arguments were supported.

Comment: Which version of Python allows an arbitrary number of arguments?  In 3.8 `gcd` expects exactly 2.

Comment: @MarkRansom you're right, this was added in 3.9 should have included that

Answer (score 1):

For Python versions earlier than 3.9, you can use `functools.reduce()` to build up the result by processing two elements at a time:

```py
from functools import reduce
from math import gcd

reduce(lambda x, y: gcd(x, y), nums, nums[0])
```